# Codeigniter get keys of language-files

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks, internationalization

I'm running into a I18N-problem here.

I have a database with several variables stored. (e.c. *mod_sales*)

To make my site I18N-able I'm using the language-class of CI-framework to read a line of a language-file
(e.c. *$this->lang->line('mod_sales');* ).

This will return me the value of that language-variable out of the language-file
(e.c. *$lang['mod_sales'] = "Sales";*) or in german (*$lang['mod_sales'] = "Verkauf";* )

Now here's the problem: I'm trying to reverse that procedure to get the key-value of that lang-array. Say I'm running my site in german and searching for "Verkauf" I wanna get "mod_sales" - exactly the same as if I'd run the site in english and would search for "sales".

Is there any implemented method to get there, or do I have to handle this by array-functions (if thats even possible)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it out (with help of CI-Guys from http://webchat.freenode.net/ #codeigniter):

I can access the array by using $var = $this->lang->language.

Now I can use array_search("val",$var); to get the key for that value.